# Comparing the values of two dictionaries using the IF condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Suppose we have the following two dictionaries and we want to compare the values in them. A key may exist in both dictionaries, but its values are different in the two dictionaries. What we want to do is, first, does this key exist in both dictionaries? And secondly, if there is one, which one is bigger? And finally, larger values are included in  two dictionary as a result. So here we have two conditions.

```
D1 = {1: 1.5, 2: 6, 3: 99, 4: 12, 5: 45, 6: 55, 7: 0}
D2 = {6: 11, 4: 15, 1: 80, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 72, 34: 1, 35: 66}

C1 = {}
C2 = {}

for d1 in D1.values():
    for d2 in D2.values():
        if d1 in d2 or d2 in d1:
            continue
        if d1 > d2:
            C1 = d1
        if d2 > d1:
            C2 = d2
print(C1)
print(C2)
```

The output is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 9
      7 for d1 in D1.values():
      8     for d2 in D2.values():
----> 9         if d1 in d2 or d2 in d1:
     10             continue
     11         if d1 > d2:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

While we expected the answer to be as follows:

```
{2: 6, 3: 99, 6: 55, 7: 0}
{1: 80, 4: 15, 5: 72, 34: 1, 35: 66}
```

Where is the problem with the codes and what codes should we use?

Comment: `D1.values()` If you want to iterate over the keys of the dictionary, shouldn't you use `D1.keys()`?

Comment: Maybe you want `.keys()` instead of `.values()`.

Comment: My intention is to first compare the keys in two dictionaries, which keys are present in both dictionaries. Then, if there is a key in both dictionaries, compare their values. Select the values that are large in the first dictionary and put them in a filtered dictionary corresponding to the existing dictionary, and the same for the second dictionary.

Comment: What to do in case of ties?

Comment: Do you need new dicts, or can you modify the original ones?

Comment: My intention is to first compare the keys in two dictionaries, which keys are present in both dictionaries. Then, if there is a key in both dictionaries, compare their values. Select the values that are large in the first dictionary and put them in a filtered dictionary corresponding to the existing dictionary, and the same for the second dictionary.

Comment: Suppose we check key 4. 1- Is there key 4 in both dictionaries? Answer: Yes. 2- Is the value of which key is greater? The value in the second dictionary. So, finally, we put its value together with the key in a dictionary specific to the second dictionary, where larger values are placed there. Of course, it is the same for the first dictionary.

Comment: We have already created a new dictionary to put the larger values into them after comparing, a new dictionary for the first dictionary and one for the second dictionary.

Comment: If you want to do what was said, how do you write the code from the beginning?

Comment: Hmm, you keep repeating yourself without answering the questions...

Comment: I apologize, unfortunately, I am not a professional and I cannot deliver the content correctly. Dear friend, he got the answer we wanted, which is what I meant. Thank you for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need something like that if I understand correctly.

```
D1 = {1: 1.5, 2: 6, 3: 99, 4: 12, 5: 45, 6: 55, 7: 0}
D2 = {6: 11, 4: 15, 1: 80, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 72, 34: 1, 35: 66}

C1 = {}
C2 = {}

for key, value in D1.items():
    if (key in D2.keys()):
        _value = D2[key]
        if (value >= _value):
            C1[key] = value
    else:
        C1[key] = value

for key, value in D2.items():
    if (key in D1.keys()):
        _value = D1[key]
        if (value >= _value):
            C2[key] = value
    else:
        C2[key] = value

print(C1)
print(C2)
```

```
{2: 6, 3: 99, 6: 55, 7: 0}
{4: 15, 1: 80, 5: 72, 34: 1, 35: 66}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 9
      7 for d1 in D1.values():
      8     for d2 in D2.values():
----> 9         if d1 in d2 or d2 in d1:
     10             continue
     11         if d1 > d2:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

For the error, you try to use "in" on integer value at line d1 in d2, because d2 is equals to key value, which is integer here. Your dictionary is D2, not d2, you should use D as uppercase. D2.keys() is what you need, but your code won't work like you want because you tried to looping D1 keys and then D2 keys per key, and you just keep looping 7x8 = 56 times for nothing at all. You have to loop each Dictionary one by one to remove same values if lower than another one, or you can just create def for it to re-use as much as you need it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are really very professional. I wanted exactly the same answer.